# Problem with java assert keyword

Tags: java, assert

```
public void foo() 
{
    assert false; /* Line 5 */
    assert true; /* Line 6 */

}
```

What does assert do here? I am familiar with assertion statement

Comment: How can you be 'familiar with assertion statement' and not know what this does? These *are* assertion statements. I do not understand.

Answer (score 10):

With this keyword, we *assert* that a certain condition is true at that point. If it is really true at runtime, the application continues, otherwise it will throw an `AssertionError`.

Your code should throw that error on line 5.

Note that assertions are disabled by default - you have to start the application with the `-ea` option ("enable assertions").

Further reading: [Programming with Assertions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/assert.html)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a keyword that throws an `AssertionError` when a given expression evaluates to `false`. It's usually used to detect "impossible" code branches at runtime.

It's also sometimes used to check the outputs of functions. Stupid example:

```
double square(double x) {
    double result = x * x;
    assert result >= 0;
    return result;
}
```

You can also specify an error message like so:

```
assert false : "Uh oh";
```

I believe runtime assertions are only evaluated when the `java` program is started with the `-ea` option.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly this is used as Java Assertion for unit testing of application. It checks for the condition after `assert` keyword and if condition returns true then it will go ahead else result in exception.

As stated on [here](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/JUnit/What_Is_Java_assert_Statement_.html):

> "assert" statements are part of the
>   Java assertion feature introduced in
>   Java 1.4. Java assertion feature
>   allows developer to put "assert"
>   statements in Java source code to help
>   unit testing and debugging.